# Primefaces GMap not rendering with h:form

Tags: google-maps, jsf-2.2, primefaces-gmap

Primefaces GMap is not rendered when enclosed in h:form tag,

```
<h:form>

  <p:gmap id="map" center="30.3753, 69.3451" zoom="6" type="map" model="#{branchBean.map}"></p:gmap>

</h:form>
```

Map is displayed when enclosing h:form tag is removed.

Using primefaces version is 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was referencing css for gmap using id rather than class name, changed it from #map to .mapStyle and set it in styleClass attribute of gmap. Now it works nicely.